# Cannot find javax.persistence.Persistence on classpath. Assuming non JPA 2 environment. All properties will per default be traversable. Spring Boot A

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot-admin

I am developing the **spring-cloud-boot-admin** example. In this example I did nothing but still project is not able to up. If I lower down the spring-boot-starter-parent to `1.5.4.RELEASE` then it works. But if I used the latest version it fails why ? Latest version `2.0.1.RELEASE`.

I am using code from **http://www.javainuse.com/spring/boot-admin**, but used the latest dependencies.

```
17:07:21.066 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.jboss.logging - Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Log4j2LoggerProvider
17:07:21.087 [background-preinit] INFO org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.0.9.Final
17:07:21.089 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.TraversableResolvers - Cannot find javax.persistence.Persistence on classpath. Assuming non JPA 2 environment. All properties will per default be traversable.
17:07:21.105 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.ValidationXmlParser - Trying to load META-INF/validation.xml for XML based Validator configuration.
17:07:21.107 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.ResourceLoaderHelper - Trying to load META-INF/validation.xml via TCCL
17:07:21.108 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.ResourceLoaderHelper - Trying to load META-INF/validation.xml via Hibernate Validator's class loader
17:07:21.108 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.ValidationXmlParser - No META-INF/validation.xml found. Using annotation based configuration only.
17:07:21.292 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator - Loaded expression factory via original TCCL
17:07:21.292 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator as ValidatorFactory-scoped message interpolator.
17:07:21.292 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.TraverseAllTraversableResolver as ValidatorFactory-scoped traversable resolver.
17:07:21.292 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.ExecutableParameterNameProvider as ValidatorFactory-scoped parameter name provider.
17:07:21.292 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.DefaultClockProvider as ValidatorFactory-scoped clock provider.
17:07:21.292 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.scripting.DefaultScriptEvaluatorFactory as ValidatorFactory-scoped script evaluator factory.
```

**SpringBootAdminApplication**

```
@EnableAdminServer
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootAdminApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootAdminApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.formLogin().loginPage("/login.html").loginProcessingUrl("/login").permitAll();
            http.logout().logoutUrl("/logout");
            http.csrf().disable();

            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login.html", "/**/*.css", "/img/**", "/third-party/**").permitAll();
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").authenticated();

            http.httpBasic();
        }
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.application.name=Boot-Admin
server.port=8093
management.security.enabled=false
security.user.name=admin
security.user.password=admin
```

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version> -->
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server-ui-login</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Issue is not with the Spring Boot version but the compatibility of concentric dependencies with the latest spring version.

Comment: How to resolved this ?

Comment: Change the dependencies version to 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT and that should work. This might be helpful for more understanding.  https://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/current/

Comment: Hi , were you able to solve this issue ? I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue also, upgrading from Spring Boot 1.5.15 to 2.1.4

Turns out I forgot to update the Spring Cloud version to one which was compatible with Spring Boot 2. Updating the version to `Greenwich.RELEASE` solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use new version 2.0.0.SNAPSHOT only thich version is supporting spring boot 2.0+, just use repository:

```
<repository>
<id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
<name>Sonatype Nexus Snapshots</name>
<url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
<snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
</snapshots>
<releases>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
</releases>
```

And then for server application import:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-server</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

For client:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Ok I will try this today and let you know